# Как обратиться к столбцу сводной таблицы после GROUPBY?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть таблица, из которой я делаю сводную таблицу путём группировки операций и максимальных сумм для этого типа операций. После этого я хочу взять 5 минимальных значений путём nsmallest, но возникает ошибка. Как можно в полученной сводной таблице обратиться к столбцу MAX ?[image: Полученная сводная таблица][image: Ошибка при обращении к столбцу max]

Comment: Приведите воспроизводимый фрагмент исходных данных и свой код в электронном виде.

Comment: А print(a.columns) что говорит? Возможно, столбец называется 'amount max', но точно не помню, проще самому проверить, просто посмотрев список столбцов. Либо там двухуровневая индексация, но с ней я уже не помню как работать.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо CrazyElf в комментах выше.
Решается это следующим образом:

```
    a = first_group.groupby(['tr_description']).agg(['max']).sort_values([('amount', 'max')])[:5]
```

Comment: nsmallest(5, [('amount', 'max')]) тогда тоже должно работать как и sort_values. Значит всё-таки двухуровневая индексация там.

Comment: Да, именно так.